# For loop with multiprocessing does only the first loop

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I need to run 2 process at the same time. In the first file I have a for loop which call the function to run the 2 methods in parallel, but it does only a loop

In the first file:

```
for i in range(5):
    class1.runInParallel(class1.acquireF(a, b), class1.readS(c,d))
```

And in class1:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
class Class1:

     def acquireF(self,a,b):
        #do something

     def readS(self,c,d):
        self.tSleep = 3
        #do something

     def runInParallel(self, acquireF, readS):
         p1 = Process(target = acquireF)
         p1.start()
         p2 = Process(target = readS)
         p2.start()
         p1.join()
         p2.join()
```

I read that it should be about the fact that the main process doesn't wait for its child to finish. Is it so? how can i solve it? Thanks

Could this be a good solution? 
In the first file:

```
Thread(target = class1.acquireF(a,b)).start() 
Thread(target = class1.readS(c,d)).start()
```

And just the methods acquireF and readS in class1

Answer (score 0):

Process.join() waits for the process to finish, since we don't know what you put in your processes we can't really help.

My wild guess is that you're blocked in acquireF because of p1.join().

Comment: Thanks for the answer! do you think that the solution i proposed in the comments is valid? i cannot see if the 2 processes are parallel

Comment: Do not write it in the comments if it is a part of the question, please edit the question itself